# Caesar cypher in Python

Tags: python, encryption, substitution

I am new to python and I want to write a program that asks for a  line of input (each number will be separated by a single space.) It would use a simple letter-number substitution cipher. Each letter will be appointed a number. So 1 = a, 2 = b and 3 = c until it reaches 26 = z. From there, however, the cipher would continue on so; 27 = a, 28 = b etc. 0's will be a space. The program will only use 0's and positive numbers. It would also print out the decryption of the message. For example:

**Please type a code:** 8 5 12 12 15

hello

and another example:

**Please type a code:** 16 25 20 8 14 0 9 19 0 3 15 15 12

python is cool

At the moment i have tried turning the alphabet into a list like this;

```
    n = int(input("Please type a code: ")
    x =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
```

...and then referring back to it later. However, im not exactly sure how this would work. I've also tried using the .replace() function. Like this:

```
    n = int(input("Please type a code: ")
    n = n.replace('1','a') #all the way until z and then loop it.
    print(n)
```

and so and and so on. But again, i have no idea how to do this properly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058830/assigning-alphabetical-letters-to-numbers-in-python-caesar-cipher) again.

Comment: There seem to be at least a dozen _Caesar cipher_ questions (in the related list) on the right.  Make some effort to do homework yourself.  A couple of lines of code that you've presented isn't remotely close to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split()`

```
numbers = input("Please type a code: ").split()

# ['16', '25', '20', '8', '14', '0', '9', ',19', '0', '3', '15', '15', '12']
```

Use `for .. in ..`

```
for num in numbers:
    print( x[int(num)] )
```

If you use `0` as `space` you have to add `space` at the begginig of list

```
x = [' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', .... ]
```

now  `x[0] == ' '`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function such as the following:

```
>>> def numerate(char):
...    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
...    place = alpha.index(char)
...    return alpha
...
>>> sent = raw_input('Enter your sentence to be encrypted: ')
Enter your sentence to be encrypted: python is so cool
>>> encrypted = []
>>> for k in sent:
...    encrypted.append(numerate(k))
...
>>> encrypted
[15, 24, 19, 7, 14, 13, 26, 8, 18, 26, 18, 14, 26, 2, 14, 14, 11]
```

Now you just have to reverse this to 'denumerate', or decode it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this helps!this is my simple Caesar cypher code**

Encryption code

```
l=[' ','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
demeg=raw_input("plz enter your message for encryption:")
key=raw_input('Enter your encryption key(key must be a number): ')
m=list(demeg)
le=len(m)
message=[]
j=0
while le>0:
    p=[i for i,x in enumerate(l) if x == m[j]]
    p=p[0]
    p=p+int(key)
    p=str(p)
    message.append(p)
    j+=1
    le-=1

message=' '.join(message)   
print message
```

this is my decryption code

```
l=[' ','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
get=raw_input('Please type a code for decryption: ')
key=raw_input('Enter your secret decryption key: ')
st=str(get)
m=st.split()
n=len(m)
i=0
message=[]
while n>0:

    s=m[i]
    s=int(s)
    s=s-int(key)
    if s>26:
        s=s-26
    word=l[s]
    message.append(word)
    i+=1
    n-=1
meg=''.join(message)
print meg
```