# Caesar shift cypher

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm working on a simple Caesar Cipher in python using `chr()` and `ord()`

Here's my code:

```
 key = 13
 newString = ''
 if mode == 'decrypt':
     key = -key
 for c in message:
     newString += chr(ord(c) + key)
 print newString
```

But something funny happens!

When I input: `"Hello world!"`, I get back `"Uryy|-?|yq."`

Looks about right, right?

But when I try deciphering it,

I get: `Hello 2old!`

Any insights? I'm thinking it has to do with `chr()` returning something like this: `'\x84'`

Comment: ok, sounds like you have a hypothesis as to what is going wrong... why don't you test it?

Comment: Have you considered overflow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caesar cypher in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059435/caesar-cypher-in-python)

Comment: One curiosity is that `Hello World!` has 12 characters, but the encrypted text (`Uryy|-?|yq.`) only has 11 characters.  Then the decrypted text has 11 too.  So, the first issue is 'which character went missing and why'?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the `w`, because it has a character code of 119, and add 13 is 132, which is not a normal character

Comment: That, I guess, depends on your definition of 'normal' character. It is a perfectly normal byte, but in the 8859-x codesets corresponds to a C1 control character (IND, to be precise; C1 Controls (0x80 - 0x9F) are from ISO/IEC 6429:1992).  In some of the Windows code pages (CP1252, for example), 0x84 corresponds to a printing character (U+201E DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK for CP1252).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"Hello world!"` is 12 characters, but `"Uryy|-?|yq."` is 11 (and so is `"Hello 2old!"`).

The cause of this is that the new ASCII code of the `w` is 132 instead of 119. Which is the `'\x84'` code.

If you do it in the IDLE and instead of `print` just type the variable, it outputs the string with `\x84`, but if you print it, it replaces it with an invalid character. If you input the exact string (with the `\x84`) it returns "Hello world!". If you don't understand the `\x84` I suggest you research character codes and hexadecimal.

---

And a traditional Caesar shift keeps all characters as letters, not others, like punctuation marks, pipes and `132`.

- `A` has the character code of 65 (in decimal)
- `a` is 97

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher, the encryption and decryption are:

"E_n(x) = (x + n) \mod {26}."

and

"D_n(x) = (x - n) \mod {26}."

respectively.

Use the character offsets of 65 and 97 and do what the Wikipedia article says.